Sudo apt update does not go through
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade   
Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.82), connection timed out 
Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.83), connection timed out 
Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.81), connection timed out 
Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.81), connection timed out 
Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.82), connection timed out 
Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.83), connection timed out                                                                                                                 Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease 
Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com:http:                                                                                                                                                                                               Reading package lists... Done
                                                                                                                                W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  
Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'                                                     W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease    
Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.82), connection timed out       
Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.83), connection timed out     
Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.81), connection timed out     
Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.81), connection timed out       
Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.82), connection timed out    
Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.83), connection timed out    
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com :http:                                               W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/InRelease  
Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com' 
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.  
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree... Done  
Reading state information... Done  
Calculating upgrade... Done   
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

